Splitting a numeric string column into a series of indicator columns
I am working on a data analysis project where I was given a very messy data set. To contextualize, the data is for mosquito surveillance. One of my columns is a series of numbers seperated by " ". Each of the numbers in these strings represent a different type of container that was tested for the presence of absence of mosquitos. For example, these are 4 examples of entries in this column, "1 3 4 5", "1 2 5 888", "1 888", and "2 3 888". There are 6 different numbers used throughout this column (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 888). I do not want to enlogate my dataset any further so I am hoping to create 6 different binary indicator columns to mark the presence or absence of each of these container types for each entry. I am fairly new to R so any suggestions or tips that you might have would be greatly appreciated!
For reference, this is the closest that I have gotten to what I'm looking for:
HHAnalysis$container_sondeo_sites <- str_split(HHAnalysis$container_sondeo_sites, " ", 6, TRUE)

However, because the numbers do not follow the same order for each entry, I have numbers in the wrong column. For example, I have 5's in my 2 column, 888's in my 1 column, etc. I appologize if my explaination is confusing. This is my frist entry and I am trying to figure out how to best convey my problem. Thanks in advance!

Hi @Rachel Zumberg, welcome to SO. You can post a part of your data with e.g. dput(head(data, 10)). On top of that it's also helpful to post an expected output. For more help on that see here

Not exactly sure what you need, but this might get you going:
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  # split `string` into separate values:
  separate_rows(string) %>%
  # from these values create new columns each:
    pivot_wider(names_from = string, values_from = string,
                # create binary indicators:
                values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 4 × 7
  someVar   `1`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `2` `888`
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           1     1     1     1     0     0
2 B           1     0     0     1     1     1
3 C           1     0     0     0     0     1
4 D           0     1     0     0     1     1

Data:
df <- data.frame(
  someVar = LETTERS[1:4],
  string = c("1 3 4 5", "1 2 5 888", "1 888", "2 3 888")
)

